# jquery media plugin for showing word and excel files

Tags: jquery, media

I'm using the [jquery media plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/media/) for showing a file sent from the server. With pdf files, it works like a charm; however, i need to be able to show word and excel documents embedded into the browser.

I tried mapping the format word to the iframe player, but it didn't worked.

```
 $.fn.media.mapFormat('docx','iframe');
```

What other options do I have? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The plugin you're using doesn't support it. A list of supported file formats can be found in its documentation: http://jquery.malsup.com/media/#players

There are a few options out there, but perhaps the easiest is Google Docs. Upload your word and/or excel file, and then follow this simple guide: https://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55244

If your documents are particularly complex then you may find that some functionality is broken, but most documents should work as expected.

Comment: Unfortunately for me, It is needed for an Intranet, which in some cases can be for terminals with no internet access